# How to make a character with real face unreal engine 4

Tags: game-engine, unreal-engine4, 3d-modelling, unreal-development-kit, unreal-blueprint

i am a beginner in game development.i used unreal engine4 for making a sample game. i successfully create a running game with the help of some tutorials.

next i need to model a character like me.also i interested to create an environment like my home. i have no idea about this.

1. is it possible to create real characters using Unreal engine 4 ?
2. How to create a new material(Real materials eg: Hose wall,floor) ?
3. How to create a characters like Gta game characters using Unreal engine?

Answer (score 2):

try to using blender, That is more simple for model creation.Then import you model to unreal engine. More fast and more easy

Answer (score 2):

1. You cannot create completely new characters inside of the Unreal Engine. To create a character you'll need a 3rd-party 3D-Modeling program. As hteshkumar said, Blender is one free possibility. Another currently free program is Fuse by Adobe, which allows you to create, rig and even animate characters.
2. You can create a new material by right-clicking on a free space in the object brwoser and select the new Material option. If you need a tutorial to get started have a llok at https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Rendering/Materials/
3. Same as the answer to question 1, but if you're really a complete beginner I'd advise you to start with something more simple than a character in GTA quality as the development of the three main characters of GTA V alone took 3 years.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MakeHuman software and export in FBX format

Answer (score 0):

My suggestions would be to use Adobe Fuse. It was formerly property of Mixamo but they were bought out. With Adobe/Mixamo Fuse creating characters is super simple in their Free to use app for Windows/OS X. You basically use their tool and make your characters with relative ease, upload to their store and they fully rig it for animation for you. It's important that you get your characters rigged, or else they won't be able to become animated for any said game engine.

In the Mixamo/Adobe Fuse, once it is rigged and submitted to their web site (for free), you can search 1000's of animations, and apply them to your Model/Rig. Then once finished getting animation packs you can download a fully rigged FBX for either Unreal Engine 4 or Unity for import into your project. Once imported into Unreal or Unity you can create Behavior Trees, State Machines, Animation Blueprints, Animation Blends, Physics Assets, etc. It's not all too complicated and it beats the alternative of modelling from scratch or purchasing third party assets from 3D modelers and other companies.

If you go the load less travelled you can model using Maya, Lightwave, 3DSMax, Cinema 4D, Modo, ZBrush, or even Blender (free). This isn't for the faint of heart! You have to model it, and then rig it yourself. This gives you the greatest customization options, however.

[www.mixamo.com](http://www.mixamo.com)

Also here is a great video on inserting rigged animated characters in Unreal Engine 4 from Mixamo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqdqMiCldtg

Answer (score 0):

1. When you say 'real' you probably mean a character that looks like a person instead of the blue man? Yes, you can model and animate using common programs like Maya / Blender, etc. Doing it well will require a ton of practice, so you should [have a look at the Unreal Marketplace for pre-made characters.](https://www.unrealengine.com/marketplace/content-cat/assets/characters)
2. If you want to have fun making materials, have a go with Substance Designer/Painter. I've had a lot of fun making procedural stuff and painting it in 3D. It uses a similar physical-based rendering workflow as the Unreal material editor so what you learn would be reusable.
3. Once again, start with the marketplace then work up to watching youtube videos on Modeling, Animating.